# Extract string between single quotes with sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed, grep

I have a thousand Delphi files (.pas), and I need to extract text from them.

The text I need is between single quotes (Pascal strings), and I only need the strings called from a particular function. E.g.: my_function('This is the string I need')

I have extracted all the lines that appear the function and added to a text file, using find and grep, but I'm unable to extract the strings.

I've been looking around the Internet for a regex to extract this strings, but I don't know how to do this. I'm trying with this:

```
sed "s/.*my_function\('(.*)'\).*/\1/" all_the_strings.txt > my_out_file.txt
```

But it doesn't work (I'm not an expert with regex...).

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr "s/.*my_function\('([^']*)'\).*/\1/p" all_the_strings.txt > my_out_file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
sed 's/.*my_function(.\(.*\).).*/\1/;'
```

Comment: It doesn't work correctly at all. If I have "my_function('This is the string I need');  // A beautiful comment", the output is "('This is the string I need');   // A beautiful comment"...

Answer (score 0):

Your solution doesn't escape parentheses at right place. In [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) they are not special metacharacters, so they match literal.

You must escape them to do grouping, so change the regexp to escape the internal ones, like:

```
sed "s/.*my_function('\(.*\)').*/\1/" all_the_strings.txt > my_out_file.txt
```